# Is Ajax token "more" secure if session is ONLY started on admin login?

Tags: php, ajax, security

After hours of research to make an Ajax request secure, I came accross `PHP Session`. I generate a token and pass this value to the session like this:

```
session_start(); 
$token = "test".rand(1,10);
$_SESSION['token'] = $token;
```

This is obviously a test scenario. My token is encrypted and generated differently. I use this session to make an XMLHttpRequest from a form to an external file in the same server which `echoes` some text I only want admin[s] to see. The file which contains the text has this url `http://127.0.0.1:8888/demo-site/content` looks like this:

```
session_start();

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {

    if (@isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "http://127.0.0.1:8888/demo-site/ajax") {
        
        if ($_GET["token"] == $_SESSION["token"]) {

            echo "Successful";

        }

    }

}
```

As you can see from the code above, it first checks if it is an AJAX Call, then where the request is coming from and lastly it compares the tokens. I pass the token to the external php file in form of link parameter, hence `$_GET["token"]` from http://127.0.0.1:8888/demo-site/content?token=xxx.

I used to check if the user is logged in, and if `true` then check if the user is an admin and if that is also `true`, then `echo` the content. Can it be that, if the php code which does `session_start()` and its respective form is **ONLY** showed to users logged in as admin, this adds an extra layer of security.

**I mean, if a hacker wants to access the external file's content, must he first crack the admin's password, and afterwards the token?**

I am assuming this given that no session is started if nobody is logged in as admin and simply the content does not show. I do not want to rely the security of this file based on a token, but the user must be an admin as well.

**Or can the hacker access the file's content if he knows what token is, regardless if the user is logged in as admin?**

With this I refer to, that the hacker knows the token but there is no `session_start()`. I have giving this a lot of thought but I am not sure if this assumption is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating things.  PHP has good Session Security - see http://php.net/manual/en/session.security.php and implement the settings recommended there. "session.hash_function" is particularly important, and means that session tokens can't be 'cracked' or guessed.

In general, brewing you own security systems in place of generally used ones is a bad idea.  Adding new layers of security on top of PHP Sessions is probably unwise unless you really know what you are doing.

First, use SSL.  This will secure your data in transit.  Next, don't use GET for tokens or passwords, as this exposes them to proxy and server logs. Once an Admin signs in, they receive a secure PHP Session token as a cookie.  This cookie is transparently used by PHP to get a session using session_start(). In your session variables, you have defined, for example, $_SESSION['admin']=1, and this means this session is an Admin. When accessing Admin data, check that $_SESSION['admin']==1.

The Client is responsible for their own security. You can't do anything about this (except use something dynamic like MFA).  What I mean is: if the Client's computer is compromised, any hacker can key-log sign in credentials, or read cookies etc, so anything you do server side will be hackable. You can add layers and layers of security, but it is bloat.

So can this be hacked? Yes, if the hacker has access to the Client computer. But then everything can be hacked. If there is no breach on the Client computer, SSL protects the communications.

Comment: Very detailed response. What type of encryption do your recommend? I have read about md5(rand(1000, 9999)) for example or bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16))

Comment: sha256 is more than sufficient.  You just set session.hash_function="sha256" in php.ini - not sure what you mean with rand() and opoenssl_...().  Read the link above very carefully and the comments below - it's a goldmine.

Comment: Ok I did that. Another point to my question, can someone access the file is the session has not started? @ChristianCerri

Comment: if session_start() is called then the session has started. You should check e.g. $_SESSION['userid'] or $_SESSION['admin'] which you set when the user signed on. If they are not correct, redirect or terminate the page.